# Chromatic number for one vertex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Chromatic number is 3 for odd cycle and 2 for even cycle.  A graph with 1 vertex is a cycle with 1 vertex $C_1$. I believe 1 is a odd number. Therefore, $C_1$ is a odd cycle. Now, I am struggling to say that the chromatic number for $C_1$ is 3.

Comment: A cycle of length $n$ has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges. A graph with one vertex and no edges is not a cycle, and its chromatic number is $1$. A graph with one vertex and one edge (a loop) is a cycle of length $1$ but it has no chromatic number as it does not admit a proper coloring. An odd cycle of length $\ge3$ has chromatic number $3$.

Comment: Wolfram classifies $C_1$ to be a cycle. If $C_1$ has an edge then what will be it's chromatic?

Comment: As I said, it has no chromatic number. Chromatic number is defined only for loopless graphs.